# How to create a word cloud from a body of text? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm attempting to create a word cloud that will be generated AFTER a user's input.

The majority of word cloud-related projects seem to link back to D3js (this repo in particular https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud)

While I can get the word cloud to function using the following

```
<div id="chart"></div>

<script>
  var text_string = "blah";

  drawWordCloud(text_string);

  function drawWordCloud(text_string){
    var stopWords = ["blah blah blah"];

    var word_count = {};

    var words = ...
      }

    var svg_location = "#chart";
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();

    var fill = d3.scale.category20();

    var word_entries = d3.entries(word_count);

    var xScale = ...;

    d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
      ....;

    function draw(words) {
     ...

    d3.layout.cloud().stop();
  }
</script>
```

I'm still facing two issues with this:

1. It only seems to work if it's directly in my index.html doc, not in a separate .js sheet.
2. It only works if I include the `<div id="chart">` in my HTML doc, which I don't want to do initially (additional HTML is added once a user enters an input and the JS runs though `addHTML += '<div id="chart">...</div>'`, which is what I'd like to do with the wordcloud - for it to be generated (based on the user's input) and only show up after the user has input and clicked a button, like the rest of the document is.

Comment: 1 you're likely loading the separate js in the head, before #chart exists, so has nowhere to draw it.  You can get around this by putting `drawWorldCloud` inside `$(function() { });` (jquery document ready).  2 same issue that you're potentially adding the chart after it's tried to draw it to the chart.  Call drawWorldClount after your `addHTML +=` has rendered the div.

Comment: @freedomn-m So `function drawWordCloud(text_string){... }` should become `$(function(drawWordCloud)(text_string) { });`? Also, what do you mean by 'jquery document ready'? (Apologies, I've only just started learning jquery).

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Understood, thank you. It still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: It should become:  `$(function() { drawWordCloud("blah"); });`